# Issue with branches in CicleCI V2.1

Tags: circleci

When trying to execute the following branches there is a build error.

extraneous key [branches] is not permitted

The code

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-s3: circleci/aws-s3@1.0.0
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: 'circleci/python:2.7'
    branches:
      only:
        - master
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: 'move file x to upload folder'
          command: 'mkdir upload | mv *.ps1 upload/'
      - run:
          name: 'move file y rules to upload folder'
          command: 'mv *.json upload/'
      - aws-s3/sync:
          from: './upload/'
          to: 's3://az-patching-runbooks'
          overwrite: true
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#branches) says:

> (...) If you are using 2.1 config, you will need to add a workflow in order to use filtering [for branches].

(text inside bracket [] is my own addition).

So add a [workflow](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#workflows) like in [this example](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#full-example) that should look something like this:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-s3: circleci/aws-s3@1.0.0
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: 'circleci/python:2.7'
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: 'move file x to upload folder'
          command: 'mkdir upload | mv *.ps1 upload/'
      - run:
          name: 'move file y rules to upload folder'
          command: 'mv *.json upload/'
      - aws-s3/sync:
          from: './upload/'
          to: 's3://az-patching-runbooks'
          overwrite: true

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

I did not test the script I wrote but it is what I gathered from the documentation.